# Custom Sort in Python

Tags: python, sorting, custom-sort

In Python,using custom sort,concatenate array elements such that the result will be greatest value from those elements.

```
T = int(input("Enter number of test cases: "))

for _ in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    array = list(map(int, input().split()))
    
    array = list(map(str, array))
    array.sort(key=lambda x: (x * 3), reverse=True if '0' in array else False)
    
    largest_num = ''.join(array)
    print(largest_num)

# it is not solving for all test cases.
```

Comment: can you provide an example

Comment: You convert the input numbers to integer, then convert it back to string.  When you do `x * 3` on a string, it repeats the string 3 times.  Perhaps you should tell us exactly what you're trying to do.  Your description doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
T = int(input("Enter number of test cases: "))

for _ in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    array = list(map(int, input().split()))

    array = list(map(str, array))
    
    
    def custom_sort(x):
    
  
        return x * 3 if '0' not in x else 0
    
    array.sort(key=custom_sort, reverse=True)
    
    largest_num = ''.join(array)
    print(largest_num)
```